# Comparator and 7 segment display

Tags: comparator, 7segmentdisplay

I am trying to make a 7 segment display that displays the symbol <, > or = depending if a > b or a=b or a < b by using the output of a comparator(7 outputs from the comparator according to the exercise). I can't figure out how a comparator gets 7 outputs when it only has 3?

EDIT: I am supposed to do this with a 2 bit 2 input comparator and 4bit 2 input comparator.

[image: Comparator]

Comment: I'm not trying to be unkind, but none of that makes any sense. For example, how are you planning on generating the ">", "=", and "<" symbols using seven-segment displays?  Second, how about posting a copy of your exercise or, at the very least, telling us which magnitude comparator you're working with? Both would be better...

Comment: Homework only helps you learn if you do it yourself. Tom's hints are more than plenty to get you there...

Comment: I wasn't really asking for a solution. I was just trying to figure out how the comparator is supposed to have 7 outputs.

Answer (score 1):

As this appears to be homework, I'll give some hints rather than an answer.

1. Look at the three patterns you need to display. Determine how many segments of the display actually ever need changing.
2. Decide what your inputs are. I presume you will have an '=' signal, a '<' signal, and a '>' signal
3. Draw out a truth table for your inputs and outputs.
4. If it is not obvious from the table what the solution is (really it should be immediately obvious once you draw out the table!), make a Karnaugh map for each of the segments that ever change.

Comment: Do I just look at what combination a=b, a<b, and a>b on my comparator's truth table and insert it in for my segment truth table? Realized that 'g' and 'd' would stay the same and that 'c' and 'e' changes.